# ¿Cómo leer una lista de objetos con RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Estoy creando un cliente para un web service con RestTemplate, este web service devuelve una lista de objetos así:

```
[
  {
    "serviceName": "string",
    "serviceType": 0,
  },
  {
    "serviceName": "string2",
    "serviceType": 3,
  }
]
```

Mi cliente está creado de esta manera:

```
    ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, List.class);
```

Y mi clase para leer los datos del Web Service es la siguiente:

```
public class UserService {

    private String serviceName;

    private Integer serviceType;

}
```

El resultado del RestTemplate en efecto es una lista, pero al tratar de iterar esa lista y obtener mis objetos del tipo UserService obtengo un **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ...**

Cómo debería usar el RestTemplate correctamente para poder leer la lista de objetos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta línea:

```
ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, List.class);
```

Así como está, getForEntity() retorna un solo objecto. Entonces tienes que envolver tu clase UserService en otra clase que contenga la lista:

```
public class UserServiceList {
    private List<UserService> userServices;
 
    public UserServiceList() {
        userServices= new ArrayList<>();
    }
 
    // getter/setter
}
```

y luego:

```
UserServiceList userServiceList = restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl, UserServiceList.class);
```